# How to vertically align input fields that has different length of labels in bootstrap 4.3.1?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">First Field</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="First Field" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Second Field</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Second Field" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjub0g7m/

**My Question:**

How to align the input fields vertically in order for them to become easier to read? Please check the image below for more details.

[image]

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try giving minimum width to the 'input-group-prepend'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use min width

```css
.input-group-text{
   min-width:120px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">First Field</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="First Field" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Second Field</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Second Field" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```